# How to define a class that is exactly the same as another class in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, inheritance

I'm defining some custom Exceptions in Dart.

I want in my logic to check the type of exception and base my processing on that, so I want to create distinct classes for each, for example like this :

```dart
class FailedToLoadCriticalDataException implements Exception { }  // app cannot continue
class FailedToLoadNonCriticalDataException implements Exception { } // app can continue
```

**However** I also want to pass 2 parameters when I create these types of exceptions, the type of API call, and the API url, and the definition for that would look like this :

```dart
class UrlCallFailedException implements Exception {
    
    String _dataTypeName;
    String _urlEndpoint;
  
    UrlCallFailedException([this._dataTypeName, this._urlEndpoint]);
  
    @override
    String toString() {
      return "(${this.runtimeType.toString()}) Failed to fetch $_dataTypeName ($_urlEndpoint)";
    }
}
```

Now what I want to do is (replace the initial definitions I made earlier and re)define my `FailedToLoadCriticalDataException` and `FailedToLoadNonCriticalDataException` classes so that they are exactly the code that is in the `UrlCallFailedException` class.

**Is there any way to simply say something like `class FailedToLoadCriticalDataException **is** UrlCallFailedException;` and not need to duplicate the code that defines `UrlCallFailedException` ?**

`class FailedToLoadCriticalDataException implements UrlCallFailedException{ }`  is wrong because it is "Missing concrete implementations of 'getter UrlCallFailedException._dataTypeName',.."

`class FailedToLoadCriticalDataException extends UrlCallFailedException{ }` is wrong because when I got to `throw FailedToLoadNonCriticalDataException("Foo", url);` it's expectation is that there are no params ("Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 2 found.").

Is there a way to create multiple classes that behave exactly the same as another type and differ only in their class, without duplicating all the code ?

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with this as a decent compromise :

```dart
class FailedToLoadCriticalDataException extends UrlCallFailedException { 
  FailedToLoadCriticalDataException([dataTypeName, urlEndpoint]) {
    super._dataTypeName = dataTypeName;
    super._urlEndpoint = urlEndpoint;
  }
}  
class FailedToLoadNonCriticalDataException extends UrlCallFailedException { 
  FailedToLoadNonCriticalDataException([dataTypeName, urlEndpoint]) {
    super._dataTypeName = dataTypeName;
    super._urlEndpoint = urlEndpoint;
  }
}
```

Some, but minimal, code duplication, and I can now call `throw FailedToLoadNonCriticalDataException("Foo", url);` in my code later.